# Programmatically access Sitecore user's workbox

Tags: workflow, sitecore

I would like to access a user's workbox from C# so that I can loop through all of the items in his workbox and update the workflow state for each version of the items.

I'm using Sitecore 6.2.0 (rev. 101105)

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** The following code needs to be run under under a master context - "From inside the sitecore admin". If you are running it from a web context (a page on the site) and Context.Database is "web" then you need to replace all instances of Sitecore.Context.Database with Factory.GetDatabase("master")

---

First you need to get all the workflows

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflows();
```

Then foreach workflow you need to get all the states:

```
workflow.GetStates();
```

Then for each state you can get all the items

```
var itemDataUris = workflow.GetItems(state);
```

GetItems returns a list of dataUris 
So if you are currently logged in with the user in question you can just do

```
foreach (var dataUri in itemDataUris)
{
    var item = Context.Database.GetItem(dataUri);
    //check if the item is null (if null the user doesn't have access to it
    if (item != null)
       usersWorkflowItems.Add(item); //Here you also need to somehow add which state the item is in
}
```

If are running as an admin and want to get the item for another user you need to wrap the above code in a UserSwitcher

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher.Enter(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName("sitecore\User", true));
foreach (var dataUri in itemDataUris)
    {
        var item = Context.Database.GetItem(dataUri);
        //check if the item is null (if null the user doesn't have access to it
        if (item != null)
           usersWorkflowItems.Add(item); //Here you also need to somehow add which state the item is in
    }
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher.Exit();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Be sure you're not trying to run this code in the web context... it won't work.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I'll amend the answer to make sure it says that.

Comment: Does anybody have (complete example) code for a working demo of this technique, I have not been able to get it to work on my sitecore dev instance 6.4.1 (rev. 111003 Hotfix 355338-3). I need to make an API for workbox/flow item access  --THanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure the context of where your code is running, or how often, but could you utilize the RSS feed from the user's workbox?